# OpenSSL client authentication and macos

Tags: c, openssl, openai-api, client-certificates

I'm trying to programmatically connect to Openai API to make some queries in c, but
when i call `try_connect()` it fails with:

```
SSL connect error
SSL: error:0A000410:SSL routines::ssl/tls alert handshake failure
```

here's the code:

```
void printSSLErrors()
{
    char errstr[256] = {};

    unsigned long err = ERR_get_error();

    while (err != 0)
    {
        ERR_error_string_n(err, &errstr[0], sizeof(errstr));

        printf("SSL: %s", &errstr);

        err = ERR_get_error();
    }
}

union ipaddr
{
    uint8_t octect[4];  // e.g. address 192.168.4.5 has octect[0]=192 and octect[3]=5
    uint32_t octet_networkOrder;
} openai;

// fill the fields with the correct IP address
//openai.octet[0]=xx
//openai.octet[0]=xx
//openai.octet[0]=xx
//openai.octet[0]=xx

bool try_connect()
{
    //TCP socket creation
    int fd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (fd == -1)
        return false;

    //SSL init

    ERR_clear_error();

    SSL_CTX* sslCtx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_method());

    if (sslCtx == NULL)
    {
        //SSL context creation failed
        printSSLErrors();
        return false;
    }

    // CA file setup

    if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_file(sslCtx, "/etc/ssl/cert.pem") == 0)
    {
        //SSL load CA file failure
        printSSLErrors();
        return false;
    }

    // Certificate setup

    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(sslCtx, "mycert.pem") != 1)
    {
        //SSL certificate file setup failed
        printSSLErrors();
        return false;
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(sslCtx, "mykey.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) != 1)
    {
        //SSL private key file setup failed
        printSSLErrors();
        return false;
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_check_private_key(sslCtx) != 1)
    {
        //SSL private key check failed
        printSSLErrors();
        return false;
    }

    SSL_CTX_clear_mode(sslCtx, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    SSL* m_ssl = SSL_new(m_sslCtx);

    if (m_ssl == NULL)
    {
        printSSLErrors();
        return false;
    }

    if (SSL_set_fd(m_ssl, m_fd) != 1)
    {
        printSSLErrors();
        return false;
    }

    //connecting

    sockaddr_in addr{};
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port   = htons(443);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = openai.octet_networkOrder;

    int ret = ::connect(m_fd, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    if (ret == -1)
        return false;


    if (SSL_connect(m_ssl) != 1)  // start SSL client handshaking
    {
        printf("SSL connect error");
        printSSLErrors();
        return false;
    }    

    return true;

}
```

The code has been tested with other servers that do not ask for client auth and it works fine. The `api.openai.com` asks for client auth so this code fails in try_connect().
`mykey.pem` and `mycert.pem` are files exported from the Keychain Access application starting from the `com.apple.systemdefault` certificate and private key.
I could not try on another different system..

The interesting thing is curl works fine in the same system, using the [provided](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create) curl example:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
-H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
-d '{
   "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
   "messages": [
     {
       "role": "system",
       "content": "You are a helpful assistant."
     },
     {
       "role": "user",
       "content": "Hello!"
     }
   ]
 }'
```

How can i fix this? Am i picking the wrong certificate or am i doing something wrong in the code?

UPDATE:

If i run

```
openssl s_client -connect api.openai.com:443 -servername api.openai.com -cert mycert.pem -key mykey.pem -CAfile /etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

It manages to connect

```
Connecting to 104.18.7.192
CONNECTED(00000006)
depth=2 C=US, O=Google Trust Services LLC, CN=GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C=US, O=Google Trust Services LLC, CN=GTS CA 1P5
verify return:1
depth=0 CN=api.openai.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN=api.openai.com
   i:C=US, O=Google Trust Services LLC, CN=GTS CA 1P5
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Feb 25 00:03:27 2024 GMT; NotAfter: May 25 00:03:26 2024 GMT
 1 s:C=US, O=Google Trust Services LLC, CN=GTS CA 1P5
   i:C=US, O=Google Trust Services LLC, CN=GTS Root R1
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Aug 13 00:00:42 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 30 00:00:42 2027 GMT
 2 s:C=US, O=Google Trust Services LLC, CN=GTS Root R1
   i:C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, OU=Root CA, CN=GlobalSign Root CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jun 19 00:00:42 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Jan 28 00:00:42 2028 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLA BLA BLA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN=api.openai.com
issuer=C=US, O=Google Trust Services LLC, CN=GTS CA 1P5
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4691 bytes and written 402 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

so i suppose the cert and key i have are correct and accepted by the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the cause.

`SSL_set_tlsext_host_name()` should be called before the `SSL_connect()` call to make SSL know the hostname of the server and complete the verification.

I've added such a call and now it's working.

I hope this answer will be useful to someone